# How to replace return on if condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is possible to replace by if condition instead using return while we have many condition in our program

```
var v2=[12,23,44,3,1,3,456,78,22];
  function checkresult(v2) {
    return v2 >= 18;
 }

var a= v2.filter(checkresult);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: Try not to name variables inside a function the same as a variable outside it.

Comment: Can you explain (maybe by example) the behavior you want?

Comment: You can use an "if" instead of a direct return but it will be less readable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can obviously use `conditional statements` inside a `filter` as long as you're returning a `boolean` value.

```js
var v2=[12,23,44,3,1,3,456,78,22];
function checkresult(val) {   // A suggestion to use different variable name other than v2
    if(val >= 18)
       return true;
    else if(<condition-2>)
       return true;
    else if(<condition-n>)
       return true;
    return false;
}

var a= v2.filter(checkresult);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: the `if..else` can be reduced like `return((val >= 18) || <condition-2> || <condition-2>)` .  It will return `true`, if any of the condition is true, unless it will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var a = [1,2,'a','b','a',1,'c'];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique);
```

As example this code, onlyUnique function is return unique values in array. You can change the function content.

Comment: Not sure it was the expected behavior. It looks like he wants to keep only elements having value 18 or greater.

Comment: I understood like he wants apply on multiple conditions. With this he can change function's content how he wants. Unique element just a example.